# index values always gets displayed even on setting .to_string(index=False) in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a table like this [Input Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZEa6.png). Trying to group by year and display the data. Here is the code.

```
import pandas as pd
data=pd.read_excel("Book6.xlsx",sheet_name="Sheet6")

df_new = data[['Date1','Name', 'Fruit','Price']]
df_new['Date1'] = pd.to_datetime(df_new['Date1'], dayfirst=True, errors='coerce')
result = df_new.reset_index().groupby([df_new['Date1'].dt.year,df_new['Name'],df_new['Fruit'],df_new['Price']]).agg('sum')
print(result)#.to_string(index=False))
```

Even on setting the index=False in .to_string, still the index getting displayed. Here is the output table. I dont require the index to be displayed.

[Output Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XXcs3.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for [`pandas.DataFrame.to_string,`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_string.html) just add `drop=True` to [`pandas.DataFrame.reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) :

```
result = (df_new.reset_index(drop=True)
                .groupby([df_new['Date1'].dt.year,df_new['Name'],df_new['Fruit'],df_new['Price']])
                 .agg('sum'))
```

Output :

```
print(result)

                          Price
Date1 Name Fruit Price       
2017  ghi  Cat   100      200
2018  abc  Ball  20        40
2019  abc  Apple 25        75
      ghi  Apple 25        50
2020  def  Apple 25        50
           Cat   100      200
      ghi  Ball  20        40
2021  abc  Apple 25        50
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This works for this reproducible case. I made small version of reprodicible case here. In my bigger version of the program, when i had your suggested change, i get the table in the form of tuple inside the list. Any idea how to make it to display as table.

Output:  **
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [(2018.0, 11.0, 45, abc, Fixed, 45.0), (2018.0, 11.0, 46, son, Fixed, 60.0), (2018.0, 11.0, 48, abc, Fixed, 35.0), (2018.0, 11.0, 48, abc, Fixed, 45.0), (2018.0, 12.0, 49, abc, Duplicate, 10.0), (2018.0, 12.0, 50, abc, Fixed, 5.0)]**

Comment: .. Any idea, why the table gets displayed as List of Tuples? ..    Empty DataFrame Columns: [] Index: [(2018.0, 11.0, 45, abc, Fixed, 45.0), (2018.0, 11.0, 46, son, Fixed, 60.0), (2018.0, 11.0, 48, abc, Fixed, 35.0), (2018.0, 11.0, 48, abc, Fixed, 45.0), (2018.0, 12.0, 49, abc, Duplicate, 10.0), (2018.0, 12.0, 50, abc, Fixed, 5.0)]